# AWS CNN-QR forecast without futurefilling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-forecast

I am currently using AWS Forecasting service. I have filling policy for related data set. Since I use CNN-qr I do not declare future filling for filling, however It gives an error as follows. Why is that so ?

> An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreatePredictor operation: Required parameters are not found. Required : {feature_name_xxx=[futurefill],

EDIT:

I cannot share the the whole code bu this is the relevant part. I am using lambda function

> ```
> - AttributeName: feature_name_xxx
>  FeaturizationPipeline:
>    - FeaturizationMethodName: filling
>      FeaturizationMethodParameters: {"backfill": "mean",
>                                      "middlefill": "mean"}
> ```

Comment: Hi, can you share the source code?

Comment: I am not allowed to share the source code but this is my part of the config file